# Maximum safe temperature for my laptop?

Tags: laptop, amd-radeon, overheating

My HP laptop overheats even while playing basic games and goes up to 79c with an average of 89 c.

What's the safe working temperatures for a laptop.

configuration- i7 7th gen processor
8gb ram
Windows 10
AMD r7 m440 gpu

My laptop is 1 month old and I have reapplied the thermal paste and cleaned the fan.

I just wish to know the safe working temperature range as it seems to run too hot.

Comment: You might want to open it up (if that's something you are comfortable with) and clean out dust/lint accumulations in the cooling path.

Answer (score 1):

High temperatures reduce lifespan of the components. But 69° average isn't bad for the GPU.

I would advice not to force max speed, the EC knows how to handle heat and will kick up the fans when needed.

Answer (score 0):

In order to see learn safe temperature limits of your hardware, use `sensors` (`lm-sensors` package) or `xsensors` programs. They give the following output (your may be different depending on your hardware):

```
$ sensors    
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +50.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +49.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +48.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +44.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +47.0°C  (high = +84.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan:    0 RPM
Video Fan:        0 RPM
CPU:            +50.0°C  
Ambient:        +36.0°C  
Ambient:        +48.0°C  
SODIMM:         +39.0°C
```

`xsensors`:

[image: xsensors]

the bars below temperatures illustrate how "normal" current temperature is.

But generally speaking, 70 degrees centigrade for laptop hardware is not much - it usually shuts down at about 100 degrees C.

Consider cleaning your hardware with compressed air and maybe changing thermal paste.

**Answer to your edit:** a good laptop should not overheat. Thermal shutdown is the "panic button" of overheating computer, which trying to avoid damaging hardware, completely shuts down. A good computer should control the temperature by increasing fan speed and decreasing CPU/GPU speed when needed to remain operational. I would ask for a new laptop or my money back.

Comment: these are for linux. I wish to know something for windows. I am confident my laptop is overheating than normal. i just wish to know what is max safe temperature at which my laptop can run continuously without having any future issues

Comment: Temperatures are not OS dependent. Also, the recommended operating temperature of your laptop will be documented in the system documentation. You should read the technical manuals for your computer from the manufacturer website.